# How to create a recursive cte query that will push parent ids and grandparent ids into an array

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a postgresql table that I am trying to create. This is my cte and I am inserting values here

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE section (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES section(id) DEFERRABLE,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE );
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
INSERT INTO section VALUES (1, NULL, 'animal');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (2, NULL, 'mineral');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (3, NULL, 'vegetable');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (4, 1, 'dog');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (5, 1, 'cat');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (6, 4, 'doberman');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (7, 4, 'dachshund');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (8, 3, 'carrot');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (9, 3, 'lettuce');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (10, 11, 'paradox1');
INSERT INTO section VALUES (11, 10, 'paradox2');
SELECT setval('section_id_seq', (select max(id) from section));

WITH RECURSIVE last_run(parent_id, id_list, name_list) AS (
  ???
SELECT id_list, name_list
FROM last_run ???
WHERE ORDER BY id_list;
ROLLBACK;
```

I know that a recursive query is the best possible way, but am not sure how exactly to implement it. What exactly goes in the ???
What im trying to get is the table below:

```
id_list |       name_list        
---------+------------------------
 {1}     | animal
 {2}     | mineral
 {3}     | vegetable
 {4,1}   | dog, animal
 {5,1}   | cat, animal
 {6,4,1} | doberman, dog, animal
 {7,4,1} | dachshund, dog, animal
 {8,3}   | carrot, vegetable
 {9,3}   | lettuce, vegetable
 {10,11} | paradox1, paradox2
 {11,10} | paradox2, paradox1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could to use several recursive CTEs in single query: one for the valid tree and another one for paradoxes:

```
with recursive
  cte as (
    select *, array[id] as ids, array[name] as names
    from section
    where parent_id is null
    union all
    select s.*, s.id||c.ids, s.name||c.names
    from section as s join cte as c on (s.parent_id = c.id)),
  paradoxes as (
    select *, array[id] as ids, array[name] as names
    from section
    where id not in (select id from cte)
    union all
    select s.*, s.id||p.ids, s.name||p.names
    from section as s join paradoxes as p on (s.parent_id = p.id)
    where s.id <> all(p.ids) -- To break loops
  ) 
select * from cte
union all
select * from paradoxes;
```

Result:

```
┌────┬───────────┬───────────┬─────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ id │ parent_id │   name    │   ids   │         names          │
├────┼───────────┼───────────┼─────────┼────────────────────────┤
│  1 │      ░░░░ │ animal    │ {1}     │ {animal}               │
│  2 │      ░░░░ │ mineral   │ {2}     │ {mineral}              │
│  3 │      ░░░░ │ vegetable │ {3}     │ {vegetable}            │
│  4 │         1 │ dog       │ {4,1}   │ {dog,animal}           │
│  5 │         1 │ cat       │ {5,1}   │ {cat,animal}           │
│  8 │         3 │ carrot    │ {8,3}   │ {carrot,vegetable}     │
│  9 │         3 │ lettuce   │ {9,3}   │ {lettuce,vegetable}    │
│  6 │         4 │ doberman  │ {6,4,1} │ {doberman,dog,animal}  │
│  7 │         4 │ dachshund │ {7,4,1} │ {dachshund,dog,animal} │
│ 10 │        11 │ paradox1  │ {10}    │ {paradox1}             │
│ 11 │        10 │ paradox2  │ {11}    │ {paradox2}             │
│ 11 │        10 │ paradox2  │ {11,10} │ {paradox2,paradox1}    │
│ 10 │        11 │ paradox1  │ {10,11} │ {paradox1,paradox2}    │
└────┴───────────┴───────────┴─────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d8799a8de66e77f2c96a93d4eed585ec)

As you can see the result includes two unwanted rows: `{10}, {paradox1}` and `{11}, {paradox2}`. It is up to you how to filter them out.

And it is not clear what is the desired result if you append yet another row like `INSERT INTO section VALUES (12, 10, 'paradox3');` for instance.